# Let $D$ be a principal ideal domain. Show that every proper ideal of $D$ is contained in a maximal ideal of $D$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I know that a PID must satisfy the Ascending chain condition. So Im guessing its going to involve that in the argument some way but Im not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Are you working with rings without identity or in the absence of the axiom of choice or something? Assuming identity and the axiom of choice, this is true for all rings, not just PIDs...

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the ascending chain property holds for PIDs then you may prove your claim by contradiction.

Let $R$ be a PID. Assume there exists a proper ideal $J \subsetneq R$ which is not contained in a maximal ideal. Set $I_0=J$. For every finite sequence

$$ J=I_0 \subsetneq I_1 \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq I_n $$

exists an ideal $I_{n+1}$ such that $I_n\subsetneq I_{n+1}$, otherwise $I_n$ was maximal, which is not possible, as $J$ is not contained in a maximal ideal. Hence, we constructed a ascending chain of ideal, which never gets stationary. This contradicts the ascending chain property of our ring.

The general case when $R$ is just assumed to be unital can be proved using Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in a Noetherian ring, any non-empty set of ideals has a maximal element (with respect to inclusion). And a PID is certainly Noetherian, since every ideal is generated by one element.

So given a PID $D$ and a proper ideal $I$ of $D$, let $S$ be the set of proper ideals containing $I$. $S$ is non-empty since it contains $I$, hence has a maximal element $M$.

If $M$ is not a maximal ideal, then there is a proper ideal $N$ with $M\subset N$, but then $M$ is not a maximal element of $S$. Hence $M$ is in fact a maximal ideal of $D$.